# How can I save custom meta to one global value?

Tags: custom-field, globals

I have added a custom meta box to one of my custom post types. It contains a checkbox that will indicate that this is the "featured monthly product" (there can only ever be one).

When I check this box, I would like to update a global custom value which is then accessible anywhere.

In other words: I would like to update a custom meta field without being post-specific.

Is this possible?

I know there is an option of creating a global options page, but I need this to be within edit.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider that when you add a metabox, nothing force you to save the value in post meta field, you can save a global option from metabox as well.

```
function my_add_custom_box() {
  $screens = array( 'post' ); // add or replace with your cpt name
  foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
    add_meta_box(
      'my_sectionid', __( 'Featured Monthly Product', 'my_textdomain' ), 'my_inner_custom_box',
      $screen
    );
  }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_custom_box' );


function my_inner_custom_box( $post ) {
  wp_nonce_field( 'my_inner_custom_box', 'my_inner_custom_box_nonce' );
  $value = (int) get_option( 'featured_monthly_product') === (int) $post->ID ? 1 : 0;
  echo '<label for="featured_monthly_product">';
  _e( "Is this the Featured Monthly Product?", 'my_textdomain' );
  echo ' <input type="checkbox" name="featured_monthly_product" value="1"' . checked(1, $value, false) . ' />';
  echo '</label> ';
}

function my_save_post_option( $post_id ) {
  $nonce = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'my_inner_custom_box_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
  if ( ! $nonce ) return $post_id;
  if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my_inner_custom_box' ) ) return $post_id;
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;
  $checked = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'featured_monthly_product', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 
  if ($checked > 0) {
    update_option( 'featured_monthly_product', $post_id );
  } elseif ( (int) $post_id === (int) get_option('featured_monthly_product') ) {
    delete_option('featured_monthly_product');
  }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_post_option' );
```

You don't explain what you want to save on that custom value, so I guessed you want to store the post ID, change the code accordingly if not.

The code above show a metabox with a checkbox. When you save post, if the checkbox is checked, the current post id is saved into option `featured_monthly_product`.

If the checkbox is uncheched and the post was the featured monthly  product the option is deleted.

If you want to globalize that value, use

```
add_action('init', 'globalize_featured_monthly_product');

function globalize_featured_monthly_product() {
  global $featured_monthly_product;
  $featured_monthly_product = get_option('featured_monthly_product');
}
```

After that, wherever you need the featured monthly product id, just use:

```
global $featured_monthly_product;
// just an example:
echo "The featured monthly product id is: " . $featured_monthly_product;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise you could use options like this. Thank you very much.